# How do I safely sign and encrypt a message with kerberos?

Tags: c, cryptography, kerberos

I'm trying to find a safe way to authenticate a user with kerberos and encrypt a message using the credentials from the authentication (the user's ticket). Can I just grab the session and private key from a krb5_creds and directly use it to sign with DSA and encrypt with AES using something like OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to choose too complex way, but in general it's possible. The [GSSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provide the corresponding API. Look at the examples from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use [EncryptMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. I recommend you additionally to read [the old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985043.aspx) written by Keith Brown and try the SSPI Workbench tool (see [here](http://www.theserverside.net/user/userthreads.tss?user_id=378076)).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I spent last night looking at GSSAPI and SASL. It's going to take some time to get through all of this. :-)

Comment: @JonBringhurst: As I wrote it's really not simple, but at least good to have some working demos. Just writing of the program based on the documentation only would be too hard.